# Recursive hierarchical joining output with spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Scala and Spark and need some help.

I'm  trying to join two data frames, with the first data frame repeating recursively. Each recursion would be numbered in the output. An example is below.

The first data frame is:

```
people.show()
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| record_id | record_name | branch |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
|         1 | one         |      9 |
|         2 | two         |      8 |
|         3 | three       |      9 |
|         4 | four        |     13 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

The second data frame is:

```
branch.show()
+--------+-------------------+
| branch | branch_supervisor |
+--------+-------------------+
|      9 |                10 |
|      8 |                11 |
|     10 |                12 |
|     11 |                12 |
|     13 |                14 |
+--------+-------------------+
```

The results would join the two data frames on branch, then recursively take the branch_supervisor from the joined and find that branch_supervisor n number of times until it cannot a branch_supervisor. Also, each level of the hierarchy would be numbered. For example, level 1 for record_id 1 is; branch 9 has branch_supervisor 10, level 2 is; branch 10 has branch_supervisor 12, etc.

The output would look like:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------------+-------+
| record_id | record_name | branch | branch_supervisor | level |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------------+-------+
|         1 | one         |      9 |                10 |     1 |
|         1 | one         |     10 |                12 |     2 |
|         2 | two         |      8 |                11 |     1 |
|         2 | two         |     11 |                12 |     2 |
|         3 | three       |      9 |                10 |     1 |
|         3 | three       |     10 |                12 |     2 |
|         4 | four        |     13 |                14 |     1 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-------------------+-------+
```

Is this possible?